# second level extraction from xml file after deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
  <Configuration xmlns="http://test.com/SConfiguration">
   <Settings>
     <setting owner="MyServer" name="AllowEditOnAreas" value="0"/>
     <setting owner="MyServer" name="ApplicationId" value="10"/>
     <setting owner="MyServer" name="Port" value="3000"/>
   </Settings>
   <PPDUs>
     <PDU type="1" state="Enabled"/> 
     <PDU type="2" state="Enabled"/> 
     <PDU type="3" state="Enabled"/> 
   </PPDUs>
  </Configuration>
```

I have the XML file shown above that I want to parse. I have written the below code to serialize the `settings` part of the XML file. That is the only portion that I care about. How to handle/discard the remaining portion of the XML file.
I need to extract the values to a `structure/class` which contains the following fields.
`AllowEditOnAreas`
`ApplicationId`
`Port`
How do I extract those values from the list of setting objects that I have.

```
public class XmlSettingsManger
{
    public class setting
    {
        public string owner;
        public string name;
        public string value;

        public setting()
        {
            owner = "";
            name = "";
            value = "";
        }
    }
    public static List<setting> Read(string path)
    {
        List<setting> Settings = new List<setting>();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<setting>));
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);

        Settings = (List<setting>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return Settings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xml is case sensitive (see `setting` and `Setting`). After fixing it(assuming lowercase) and taking into consideration of xml namespace,  you can easily use Linq To Xml

```
XNamespace ns = "http://cubic.com/CatsDISConfiguration";
var dict = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstring)
           .Descendants(ns + "setting")
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value, x => x.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Check it:

```
foreach(var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {item.Value}");
}
```

Comment: `Settings` refer to the enclosing XML namespace which contains a list of `setting`. What is `yourxmlstring` here ? Is it `List<setting> that is returned from function Read.

Comment: @liv2hak **(a)** see your xml again. I didn't say `Setting**s**`. **(b)** `yourxmlstring` is the xml you posted in question.